# How to delete a JSON object with the information of the DOM (or by id)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to delete a JSON Object with the information of a table.

First I declare the object empty:

```
let notas = [];
```

Then I manipulate it with user interaction, and create a `table` with the acquired information. In one of the cells I create a button to for accessing that row:

```
function añadirNota() {
        //DOING THINGS TO COLLECT DATA
        const notaObj = {
            id: Date.now(),
            dh: tiempo(),
            imp: colorPArray,
            texto: nota
        }
        notas = [...notas, notaObj];
        //CREATING TABLE AND BUTTON
        var table = document.getElementById("tablanotas");
        var row = table.insertRow(1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        //INSERT THE BUTTON WITH THE deleteRow() function
        var textoTransformado = notaObj.texto + `<button class='btn' onclick="deleteRow(this)">❌</button>`; 
        cell1.innerHTML = notaObj.dh;
        cell2.innerHTML = importancia;
        cell3.innerHTML = textoTransformado;
}


function deleteRow(r) {
    var h = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById("tablanotas").deleteRow(h);
   
}
```

And now the question, I have tried inserting this in the `deleteRow()` function to have something to compare to the object:

```
var t = document.getElementById("tablanotas"),
d = t.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
```

But I don't know what follows. Can I iterate within an object, compare to the `td` element and if they are equal, delete the object?

Comment: your question is not clear. Can you please explain it again

Answer (score 1):

It easier use ID ("someId") in your tag, than use getElementById function to retrieve tag info:

```
var textoTransformado = notaObj.texto + `<button id="someId" class='btn' onclick="deleteRow(this)">❌</button>`;
```

Comment: Hi. But that doesn't help to delete the object, I think.

Comment: Ok, so i don't understand question, sorry, i try to read again.

Comment: I,m trying to delete the object with the informatiion that `d = t.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];` that gets m

Comment: So if you want delete it from array notas, try this: pass obj onclick="deleteRow(notaObj)" via click event and after use splice method on notas.splice(index, 1) with notas.indexOf(notaObj). Splice method return array less you item (if you need to delete also notas item, do again splice with same index minus 1)